# Remove the list ID while writing to a file from R

Tags: r, file-io, formatting, string-formatting

I want to write the output of my R script to a text file. I am doing it with the help of

```
sink("filename");
```

However, my output from:

```
print(sprintf("%d%10f",key,value));
```

is in the format:

```
[1] "0  0.014806"
[1] "1  0.053434"
[1] "10  0.014806"
[1] "100  0.053434"
[1] "1000  0.014806"
[1] "10000  0.053434"
[1] "1000000  0.014806"
[1] "10000000  0.014806"
[1] "100000000  0.053434"
```

I want the output in the text file in the format:

```
0  0.014806
1  0.053434
10  0.014806
```

How can this formatting of output be done. I need to remove the [1] as well as the ""?

Comment: Have you tried `?write.table`??

Comment: And include `row.names=FALSE`

Comment: Additionally, have a look at `?cat`

Comment: quote=FALSE works. But the row.names=FALSE doesn't remove the [1]

Comment: cat worked well for me. You can add it to the answer if you wish to.

Comment: @ArkidMitra you can add your own solution. It is even encouraged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In place of:

```
print(sprintf("%d%10f",key,value));
```

I have now used:

```
cat(key,value)
```

I have already sinked the output to another file to get the desired output.